# Retrieve value from a fetchone() call in python 3

Tags: python, sqlite

I am fairly new to python and I can not find the answer to my question anywhere. Unless I just don't understand the answers given. 
I have a database cursor and I execute this command:

```
cmd = 'select value from measurement where measurement_location is ?'
crs.execute(cmd, [location_id])
print(crs.fetchone())
```

Which prints:

```
{'value': 73.97486139568466}
```

I need to use the float 73.97.... in some calculations to compute an average.
My problem is that I can't figure out how to pull the float from the fetchone() return.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`fetchone` is returning you a dictionary for each row mapping the field name in the result (only `value` in this example) with the value for that row.  To use it you can do

```
cmd = 'select value from measurement where measurement_location is ?'
crs.execute(cmd, [location_id])
row = crs.fetchone()
print(row['value'])

print(row['value'] * 100)
```

or whatever other things you want to do with that result

Comment: You could also use `row.get('value')`

Answer (score -2):

You can do something like below:

```
row=crs.fetchone()

for x in row:

    print(x)

Value=x
```

you can use value variable in your calculations

Comment: Firstly, this is not correct. Row is a dictionary. When you iterate over a dictionary using for loop, you iterate over its keys. OP wanted to get the value.
Secondly, this is a poor way to get an element from a dictionary or an array.
x will be bound to the last element of the iterable, but its taking O(n) time instead of O(1).